# Does Spark support user-defined in-memory data structure over all nodes?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am working with Spark SQL and satisfied with the beautiful features of it.

I'd like to add user-defined function (UDF) in SQL statement which Spark sql supports. I have a bitmap array data in binary format which works as a bloom filter with UDF.

Can I enforce each worker instance keeps the entire data structure (bloom filter) in memory and use it with UDF?

thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every local object referenced inside a closure will be simply serialized and transfered with corresponding task. Beyond that Spark doesn't apply any special transformations - if you have local in-memory data structure it won't change when you use it inside a task.